# I need to assign users to an Azure Active Directory Group if they are members of multiple groups. Is this possible?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-security

I have Group A, Group B and Group Collection C. I would like to only allow members into Group A if they are simultaneously a member of Group B and any group in Group Collection C

For example, User Joe Blow is a member of Group B and the third group in Group Collection C. He would be allowed into Group A.

Is this possible?

EDIT:
The answer to this question is yes, it is possible, theoretically speaking. It is supposed to be handled through Dynamic Groups.

[Dynamic membership rules for groups in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership)

However, it does not appear to work correctly for this use-case.
This query should work:

```
user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ["GroupC-1Id", "GroupC-2Id"]) -and user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ["GroupBId"])
```

But users who are only members Group C-1 still make it into Group A

This query has worked for others:

```
user.memberof any (group.objectId in ["GroupBId"]) and (user.memberof any (group.objectId eq ["GroupC-1Id"]) or user.memberof any (group.objectId eq ["GroupC-2Id"]))
```

But for me it causes users who are only members Group B to still make it into Group A.

Comment: Can you please help with steps followed through GUI or any PowerShell commands tried?

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju I've updated the question with my research thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce in my environment in powershell:

Below are the groups that are needed to be checked.

***`Group 1:`***
[image]

***`Group 2:`***
[image]

***`Group 3:`***

[image]

I have tried the scenario using **`powershell`** , where users are added to `Group-Anew` when user belongs to group1 and also belongs to any one of the groups 2 and 3.

```
$AllUsers=Get-AzureADUser

#Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<groupOb>" -RefObjectId "<userOb>"


$Newgroup=New-AzureADGroup -Description "TsInfoGroupNew group is for TsInfo" -DisplayName "Group-ANew" -MailEnabled $false -SecurityEnabled $true -MailNickName "TsInfoGroupNew"

$GroupAObjectId= $Newgroup.ObjectId

foreach($user in $AllUsers)
{
$userGroupMembership=Get-AzureADUserMembership  -ObjectId $user.ObjectId | select displayname, description , ObjectId

$userGroupMembership

if($userGroupMembership.DisplayName -eq "group1" –and ($userGroupMembership.DisplayName -eq "group2" -or $userGroupMembership.DisplayName -eq "group3" ) )
{
$allowUsers=$user.ObjectId
#below command adds the allowed users to group Group-ANew
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $GroupAObjectId -RefObjectId $user.ObjectId

}

}
```

The users are added in the expected manner after execution of the commands as required.

[image]